# Addition/Multiplication operations on loop

Tags: clojure, maps

I'm a newbie to Clojure and need some help with my code.
Here's the situation:

My first table (products) looks like : `(product_name price)`

```
([1 (candies 6.5)] 
 [2 (sweets 1.75)]
 [3 (jam 2.99)] 
 [4 (gum 1.25)])
```

My first table (products) looks like : `(customer_name product_name quantity)`

```
([1 (Sara candies 3)] 
 [2 (Joe jam 3)]
 [3 (Sara gum 1)])
```

What I'm trying to do is if i type for example Sara, I'll get the sum of the sales made by Sara, which means: (3 * $6.5 + 1 * $1.25) = $20.75 (in this case)

I'm fine for the input part (I get the name of the customer as an input from the terminal)
However, my code:

```
(defn sales_prices_with_cond [name_cus] (map
 (fn [y z]
   (if (= (str name_cus) (str (nth (first z) 1)))
   list (* (Double. (nth (second y) 1)) (Integer/parseInt (nth (second z) 2))))
   )
products 
sales))
(println (reduce + sales_prices_with_cond "Sara"))
```

Gives me the sum of ALL the sales*quantities. It's like the condition is skipped or maybe not well written ...
I also tried with (some) and got the same result...

Please Help :') .

Comment: I think this should be `(reduce + (sales_prices_with_cond "Sara"))`? Your `map` there zips the two tables - this will only work by chance anyway, when the customer and the product align. Make a map with the product prices. Then filter the sales for the customer in question. Finally reduce over that, calculate the product price, multiply by amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables don't look like valid Clojure code which makes it difficult to help you - are they strings? I would transform the first one into a map of the form:
`(def prices {"candies" 6.5}) ;etc`

Your second table would be something like:
`(def sales [["sarah" "candies" 3]]) ;etc`

And then your main function:

```
(defn sales-by-customer [name-cus]
  (->> sales
       (filter #(= (first %) name-cus))
       (map #(* (last %) (prices (second %)))
       (reduce +)))
```

Comment: Actually, the tables were given to me this way (I didn't make them myself which makes it a little bit challenging to me too). Yes, the entries are all strings but I parsed the numbers I wanted to work with in the process. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: After following your logic, I transformed my tables as you suggested and called the function. However I've got this error : Syntax error (ClassCastException) compiling at (db.clj:76:1).
class clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (clojure.lang.LazySeq and clojure.lang.IFn are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Comment: I don't understand why I have a cast exception when we're supposed to get back a number?

Comment: could be that prices is a seq instead of being a map, and so it's trying to call a seq and failing. prices need to be of the format {key1 value1 key2 value2}